# Javascript - change variable name

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
if(response.next == "2") {
  $('.imgdiff-1').attr('src', img2.src);
  $('.imgdiff-2').attr('src', img22.src);
}
if(response.next == "3") {
  $('.imgdiff-1').attr('src', img3.src);
  $('.imgdiff-2').attr('src', img32.src);
}
if(response.next == "4") {
  $('.imgdiff-1').attr('src', img4.src);
  $('.imgdiff-2').attr('src', img42.src);
}
if(response.next == "5") {
  $('.imgdiff-1').attr('src', img5.src);
  $('.imgdiff-2').attr('src', img52.src);
}

var level_img_src = "images/levels/";
var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = level_img_src + '2.jpg';
var img22 = new Image();
img22.src = level_img_src + '22.jpg';
var img3 = new Image();
img3.src = level_img_src + '3.jpg';
var img32 = new Image();
img32.src = level_img_src + '32.jpg';
var img4 = new Image();
img4.src = level_img_src + '4.jpg';
var img42 = new Image();
img42.src = level_img_src + '42.jpg';
var img5 = new Image();
img5.src = level_img_src + '5.jpg';
var img52 = new Image();
img52.src = level_img_src + '52.jpg';
```

I want instead of all those if statements to make something like this:

```
$('.imgdiff-1').attr('src', img' + response.next + '.src);
$('.imgdiff-2').attr('src', img' + response.next + '2.src);
```

This code doesn't work, but I want to change the object name dinamically with the variable that comes from ajax.

Any thoughts how to write all this code in a more compact way?

Comment: Someone's bound to suggest using `eval`. Don't. It's a bad habit to get into, and there are better ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your images into an array:

```
img = img2 = []; // empty array
img[2] = new Image();  img[2].src  = level_img_src+'2.jpg';
img2[2] = new Image(); img2[2].src = level_img_src+'22.jpg';
// etc.
```

Then pull images out by index number:

```
$('.imgdiff-1').attr('src', img[response.next].src);
$('.imgdiff-2').attr('src', img2[response.next].src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?:

```
var img2 = new Image(); im2.src=lvl_img_src+'2.jpg';

... get response...

var imgSrc = response.next + '.src';
$(.imgdiff-1').attr('src', img + imgSrc)
```